# CSV delimiter issue

Tags: java, export-to-csv, delimiter

I have a web based application used accessed from different location. At each location CSV delimiter is different. I would like to get the delimiter used in user's machine and generate CSV with that specific delimiter. Please let me know if this is possible.

Comment: Yes, that is possible. Of course it makes no sense, because delimiter for CSV is, by definition, a comma. You know, as in **Comma**-Separated-Values.

Comment: All the CSV files I have seen here have semicolon as delimiter, despite the name. Certainly the delimiter may vary.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks  andears for the reply. In my case delimiter differs based on user machine settings. Hence caught in this issue. Do u know if its possible to get user's machine specific delimiter

Comment: I was not aware there was a system setting anywhere for list delimiters. What OS are you referring to, and where do you configure that setting?

Comment: We need to go control panel-region n language - advance settings . there we can specify the delimiter. This is for windows. :)

Comment: I searched in vain for a similar setting in my Mac OS X. No guarantee that it isn’t there, but I did check the advanced settings. My MS Excel for Mac when opening a .csv file uses semicolon as separator, not comma, again I’ve searched in vain for a setting. If it’s OS specific, it’s probably hard to read the setting from Java.